# Capturing missing host names from a file separated by comma

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file1.txt and file2.txt which have few hostnames separated by comma ",". I have a working solution where I loop through the value of file2.txt and capture the values which are not in file1.txt. However, when I try to execute the same through the pipeline its not working.
Can anyone advice if by using Awk or Sed or any one-liner command to achieve the same?

**file1.txt**

host1,host2,host3,host4,host100

**file2.txt**

host2,host4

expected output:

**output.txt**

host1,host3,host100

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused: You want to list the values not in `file1.txt` but your output shows the hosts unique to `file1.txt`. Btw, do the hosts in `file2.txt` really have `.txt` at the end?

Comment: host2 = host2.txt ?

Comment: @AmitPattnaik : _when I try to execute the same through the pipeline its not working_  : I don't see any "working solution" nor a pipeline in your question. Maybe you forgot to post it? We can't really discuss, why your program is not working, when we don't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to Ted's answer by using process substitution

```sh
# See modification below for a better approach
grep -vf <(tr , \\n < file2.txt) <(tr , \\n < file1.txt) | awk '{printf("%s%s",NR==1?"":",",$0)}'
```

The `grep` part outputs all hostnames in `file1.txt` but not in `file2.txt`, and the `awk` part merges all results into one line.

Also, this assumes that there's no `.txt` in `file2.txt`.

---

Edit: Thanks for karakfa's comment, a better approach may be

```sh
grep -xvf <(tr , \\n < file2.txt) <(tr , \\n < file1.txt) | paste -sd,
```

The `-x` option is set to match full pattern (in case there's any blank).

Comment: We both use process substitution :-) -  but your solution is nicer. Got my vote.

Comment: `... | paste -sd,` will be better.

Comment: Also maybe `-w` to grep so that host1 won't match host100.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `file2.txt` looks like this:

```
host2,host4
```

You could use `diff` and [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). I replace `,` with newline (`\n`) and `sort` the result for both files and give the result to `diff`:

```
diff <(tr , '\n' < file1.txt | sort) <(tr , '\n' < file2.txt | sort)
```

Output:

```
1,2d0
< host1
< host100
4d1
< host3
```

Lines starting with `<` are unique to `file1.txt` and lines starting with `>` are unique to `file2.txt`.

Comment: `comm` is probably better than `diff` here.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, indeed. It's easier to parse than the default `diff` output for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Another take. This one splits the files on commas, sorts them, and then uses `comm` to get just the entries in the first file, and stores them in an array. Then prints the elements out separated by commas to the output file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mapfile -t hosts < <(comm -23 <(tr , "\n" < file1.txt | sort) \
                              <(tr , "\n" < file2.txt | sort))
IFS=,
echo "${hosts[*]}" > output.txt
```

Or using `grep` instead of `comm`:

```
mapfile -t hosts < <(grep -Fvf <(tr , "\n" < file2.txt) <(tr , "\n" < file1.txt))
```